# React Routing - Params not seen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React project (dom -V15.5.4, router -V4.1.1, router-dom -V4.1.1). The `params` are not in the `props` variable, when inspecting the scope.

This is the Class:

```
const Main = () => (
    <main>
        <HashRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={ProductOverview}/>
                <Route path='/product/:prodId' component={Product}/>
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    </main>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Main />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now the prodId is not seen:

`<Link to={"product/"+ this.props.product.id}>  <p>{this.props.product.name}</p></Link>`

I've also tried (but this one gives an empty url: http://localhost:3000/#/):

```
<Link to="/" query={{"product":this.props.product.id}}>  <p>{this.props.product.name}</p></Link>
```

How the URL should look like: http://localhost:3000/product/1/

If this is helpful, the Product Class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Product extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div className="Product"></div>
        );
    }
}

export default Product;
```

Where is the issue? In the Link or in the Router? Was causes this issue of not getting the params value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react-router v4, the params exist in `this.props.match.params`

> A match object contains information about how a Route path matched the URL. match objects contain the following properties:
>
> - **params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path**
> - isExact - (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
> - path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested Routes
> - url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested Links

*Source: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match*

---

Your modified Product class would look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Product extends Component {
  render() {
    const { prodId } = this.props.match.params;
    return (
      <Link to={`/product/${prodId}`}>My Link Text</Link>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```